# JTree child nodes with same bounds

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree with a custom model and custom renderer. They seem to work fine, except that when I expand a node that has multiple child nodes, it draws all child nodes to the same rectangle so only the last node is visible. I can iterate through the child nodes and I can print them to the console, but the UI is different.

This is a sketch of the UI:

```
// for 1 child node:
ROOT
-- <rendered node>

//for 2 child nodes:
ROOT
|
-- <rendered node - the data of the 2nd node>

//for 3 child nodes:
ROOT
|
|
-- <rendered node - the data of the 3rd node>
```

I figured out that the BasicTreeUI uses getPathBounds() to determine the bounds of a certain node. Here is how I check it:

```
doStuffWithTree(JTree tree) {
   tree.expandNode(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
       TreePath tp = tree.getPathForRow(i);
       tree.makeVisible(tp);
       System.out.println("Bounds of row " + i + ": " + tree.getPathBounds(tp));
   }
}
```

With this check I get that all the nodes - except the node 0 - have the same bounds.

I tried a few tricks with expanding the tree, e.g. expanding all nodes starting from the first; then starting from the last - they all have the same effect.

Finally, the question: what class could I modify to fix this behavior? Are there any known workarounds?

UPDATE

Apparently, something needs to be fixed on the TreeNode implementation. Also, I need to correct myself: I didn't have a custom model, but a cusomtom TreeNode. Here is the SSCCE:

```
package com.example.jtree;

//lots of obvious imports

public class JTreeBoundsExample extends JFrame {

public static void main(String... args) {
    JTreeBoundsExample m = new JTreeBoundsExample();
    m.setSize(275, 300);
    m.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    m.setVisible(true);
}

public JTreeBoundsExample() {
    ValueTreeNode root = new ValueTreeNode(null, "root");
    ValueTreeNode category = new ValueTreeNode(root, "category");
    category.put("k1", new ValueTreeNode(category, "v1"));
    category.put("k2", new ValueTreeNode(category, "v2"));
    category.put("k3", new ValueTreeNode(category, "v3"));
    root.put("category", category);

    JTree tree = new JTree(root);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new ValueCellRenderer());

    tree.setRootVisible(false);
    tree.expandRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
        TreePath tp = tree.getPathForRow(i);
        tree.makeVisible(tp);
        System.out.println("Bounds of row " + i + ": " + tree.getPathBounds(tp));
    }

    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private static class ValueTreeNode extends HashMap<String, ValueTreeNode> implements TreeNode {

    private List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    private TreeNode parent;
    private String value;

    public ValueTreeNode(TreeNode parent, String value) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public ValueTreeNode put(String key, ValueTreeNode val) {
        ValueTreeNode old = super.put(key, val);
        if (old == null) {
            sortKeys();
        }
        return old;
    }

    private void sortKeys() {
        keys.clear();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration children() {
        final Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        return new Enumeration() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return it.hasNext();
            }
            @Override
            public Object nextElement() {
                return it.next();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAllowsChildren() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeNode getChildAt(int pos) {
        return get(keys.get(pos));
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount() {
        return size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndex(TreeNode arg0) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return size() == 0;
    }
}

private static class ValueCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        if (value instanceof ValueTreeNode) {
            ValueTreeNode vtn = (ValueTreeNode) value;
            setText(vtn.value);
        }
        return this;
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem. It's too hard to guess what is going wrong. All children should be visible.

Comment: typically, no tricks required - so you are doing something wrong :-) No possibility to come up with the "something" without seeing your code (in the shortened version of an SSCCE, of course)

Comment: The original code is part of a bigger application which was written years ago. Also, I'm (of course) not allowed to publish any part of its source. Anyway, I'm going try to reproduce it in an SSCCE and I will post here my findings.